# Do native modules have to be declared in global modules in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7

Do you have to declare native C++ modules in the  area of the IIS7 configuration? I have a native module that I'd like to use on some sites but not others.

Comment: A native module is still a .dll right? I believe they are installed in the .config files alongside managed modules.

Comment: Native modules are registered using the image attribute to point to a dll file while managed modules are registered using the type attribute to point to a fully qualified type. It's only valid to register native modules in <globalModules> and only valid to register managed modules in the system.web modules area. I tested this by trying to add the native module through the IIS manager interface. It would only let me do this in the global modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native modules need to be registered in the  area of the applicationHost.config, but in most cases they can be added or removed from a particular site by adding or removing the module by name from the system.webserver modules configuration.

```
<modules>
    <add name="NativeModule1" />
    <remove name="NativeModule2" />
</modules>
```

It is possible to a native module to kick in regardless of whether it's been added or removed from the system.webserver modules configuration (the [application request routing helper module](http://blogs.iis.net/anilr/archive/2009/03/03/client-ip-not-logged-on-content-server-when-using-arr.aspx) does this).